# React hooks setState value is undefined in first time after component was rendered

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an array of stuff that gets pulled from an api, I need to set result of that async call to my state "ordersState" and use that state value as a parameter for another component "ChartBuilder".

The issue here is that when my component "Orders" was rendered the state value at the beginning is still undefined. After I did logging I can see that the first two calls are undefined and only after that the state has value.

How to avoid this behavior ? without using timeout ?

```js
export default function Orders() {
    const [ordersState, setOrdersState] = useState();

    const getOrders = useCallback(async () => {
        setOrdersState(await foo());
      }, []);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        getOrders()
      }, [getOrders])


    console.log('ordersState ', ordersState);

    return (
        <Grid item xs={12} md={12} lg={10} sx={{ mt: 3 }}>
            <Stack spacing={3}>
                <ChartBuilder
                    title="Orders"
                    chartLabels={["Jan", "Feb", "Apr."]]}
                    chartData={[
                        { name: 'orders', data: ordersState },
                    ]}
                />
            </Stack>
        </Grid>
    )
}
```

It looks like that child component "ChartBuilder" is not re-rendering after parent component state has been changed

Comment: You can't avoid that as the parent component will render on state change. Here it will render for first time then it will call `getOrder` which will change the state and hence it will rerender. if you don't want to show component till state is loaded you can add loader component or do what is needed.

Comment: can you provide your foo() function maybe you don't get data from that.

Comment: it' s just simple api GET call. And I'm getting the data, as I mentioned after logging in console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have two options here:
set ordersState to a default value usable like an empty array with

```
useState([])
```

otherwise you need to handle the undefined case. Kind of this:

```
if (!ordersState) return (<h1>No orders</h1>)
else  return (
        <Grid ...
```

Comment: It's not really solved my problem, the state is empty now instead of undefined and after my state has values the component is not rerendering itself, I don't really get why

Comment: It looks like that child component "ChartBuilder" is not re-rendering after parent component state has been changed

Comment: There is a typo on chartLabels, a double square bracket. I don't know if it's the issue. 
If a prop changes the child component will be re-rendered.